# Are Vagrant virtual machines (Virtualbox) safe from accidental shutdown/reboots?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, vagrant

Say your host machine got shutdown abruptly or somebody pressed the reboot button and your Vagrant VM is in a running state (e.g., not on `halt` or `suspend` state). Will they survive when the host machine boots again?

Note: This is Vagrant with Virtualbox as provider.

Edit: By survive I mean not get corrupted and still be able to boot just fine either manually or automatically in case host machine shuts down due to power outage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On host shutdown, all guest VMs will be abruptly and ungracefully stopped,
unless you have taken steps to have them also gracefully shutdown.

It also depends on the type of the shutdown :
The graceful shutdown of the OS involves gracefully shutting down all
apps (or trying to within the allocated time), which happens when
manually doing shutdown or by a short press on the power button.
On the other hand, a forceful shutdown, by power outage or long
press on the power button, will have unknown consequences for both
host and guests, where the likelihood is that they will recover,
but there is always the possibility by very bad luck of being damaged.

See the following VirtualBox post for one solution:
[How to auto-shutdown guest when doing host shutdown?](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=53684#p285540),
where the following command is suggested:

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" setextradata "VM NAME" GUI/DefaultCloseAction Shutdown
```

In addition, no VM will start automatically, unless you have added a startup
script that will start it on boot (only as headless) or on login
(GUI or headless).
If you wish to do that, see for example
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45971976/165358),
which contains this sample command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" startvm kubuntu --type headless
```

Comment: There can **not** be a "gracefull" shutdown e.g. if the reset button was pressed on the host regardless what options you enable/disable in VirutalBox.

Comment: @Albin: You are right in the case of a long power-button press or a power outage. A short press will do graceful shutdown,

Comment: I think the former use case (power outage etc.) is the use case the OP is asking about, could it be that you misunderstood the question, or did I misunderstand your answer?

Comment: @Albin: Don't think so. I believe he is asking whether they will automatically restart. Otherwise, asking whether they will be usable afterward can equally be asked for the host...

Comment: Yeah, could be that as well...  well, hopefully he will clarify. Out of curiosity, is the term "graceful shutdown" used when you talk about the OS? I always thought it applies to applications (when sending a termination signal). Sorry this is sort of "off topic" but I know you don't like to go into chat...

Comment: To both actually, as the graceful shutdown of the OS involves gracefully shutting down all apps (or trying to) .

Comment: VirtualBox may have time to pause the VMs, or not.

Comment: hmmm, MS doesn't seem to use the term "officially", seem they call the ungraceful shutdown "forced shutdown" and everything else just "shutdown". But apart from that how would you call pressing the power button long? "turn off the system"? Usually I only refer to it just in the context of a restart (cold/warm)...

Comment: Edited my question for clarity

Answer (score 0):

If the host is terminated abruptly (e.g. reset button pressed) aka "ungraceful termination", the "same thing" will happen to the virtual machines currently running on that host. It's like you press the reset button on all the VMs as well. As a result, for example, all data only stored in memory (RAM) and not on the (virtual) HD will be lost etc.

In other words the VMs will **not** continue running from the point where they "left off" when e.g. the reset button was pressed on the host. Once you restart the host you can restart the VMs as well (manually or automatically if you make the appropriate settings).

If any data corruption occurred depends on the state they were in while the restart occurred. You can compare it to your experience with a regular PC, sometimes the will be errors after a cold, "ungraceful" restart sometimes there will be none (or they have been repaired automatically). It all depends on what software is installed and what the software was doing at that point.